# Check Threading Time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I just learnt about multi-threading and got the following code from some tutorial:

```
import urllib2 
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

urls = [
  'http://www.python.org', 
  'http://www.python.org/about/',
  'http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html',
  'http://www.python.org/doc/',
  'http://www.python.org/download/',
  'http://www.python.org/getit/',
  'http://www.python.org/community/',
  'https://wiki.python.org/moin/',
  ]

# open the urls in their own threads and return the results
with Pool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
```

Can someone tell me how do I found out the time taken for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to time the overall execution:

```
import sys
import time
import urllib2
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

get_timer = time.clock if sys.platform == "win32" else time.time  # precision fix

urls = ['http://www.python.org', 'http://www.python.org/about/']  # etc.

start_time = get_timer()
with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
print("Total execution time: {}s".format(get_timer() - start_time))
```

If you want to time your threads/processes individually, you should create your own function that collects the starting time at the beginning, calculates the delta after the execution and map that instead of `urllib2.urlopen`, e.g.:

```
import sys
import time
import urllib2
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

get_timer = time.clock if sys.platform == "win32" else time.time  # precision fix for Windows

urls = ['http://www.python.org', 'http://www.python.org/about/']  # etc.

def timed_function(url):
    start_time = get_timer()
    result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print("Thread finished in {}s for url: {}".format(get_timer() - start_time, url))
    return result

with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(timed_function, urls)
```